# split by string in WEKA

Tags: weka

I am trying to process typical log file from linux uptime command in Weka. I'm using the gui explorer. The problem is, the columns get interpreted as:

```
11:48:11 up 5 days
18:45
3 users
load average: 0.16
0.30
0.40
```

How can I get rid of the 'load average: ' so that I can plot the actual numerical data? I've tried to set the import string limits to 'a-z,:', but I got "No upper limit has been specified for range"

I'm actually very surprised that I could not find neither ready filter method nor a quick reference to it as it seems like a crucial functionality to me.

Comment: What about using `sed` first to get rid of the text?

Comment: I already have a logfile to look through. I can cat it and pipeline to sed, but that seems like a workaround rather than solution and I'd like to know if it's possible to make such split in weka